# Google Maps API v3 and Geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-api, geocoding

I'm using Google Maps API v3 with online billing, since I use more than daily quota.

I'm having problem using geocoding calls, I receive the error:

> This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.

The call is correctly made with my API Key:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[ADDRESS]&sensor=false&language=it&key=[myApiKey]
```

Are Geocoding calls not included in the Maps API v3? Do I have to subscribe some other different package to allow geocoding requests?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xJ26V/1/

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addresscity }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)                       
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking. I want to continue to use the method:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[ADDRESS]&sensor=false&language=it&key=[myApiKey]

and be billed of the queries over quota.

I want to know just how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pay for going over the free quota you will need a contract with Google (Google Maps API for Business). Information on how to contact a representative can be found at this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing